# Cross domain Single Sign On

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement cross-domain SSO. I have a few applications on two main domains. I want a light solution I can implement myself, meaning I don't want to deploy something like 3 more separate applications just for user access management.

The way I thought I can do this:
When user logs in, he will be redirected to two domains, and encrypted tokenid will be set as cookies on those two domains, which then will be decrypted and used to access auth app for user data.

Is this an okay approach?
Is there a problem with redirecting on log in? Asking because I don't see many recommendations to do this, even though it seems that Google does this.

Also I thought about having shared session store for all apps, but this will be hard to implement on multiple servers and will not be specific to each application.

Or is there any other solution?

Comment: OAuth is what you're looking for. The app holding credentials should be the OAuth server, and other apps just use OAuth server app to verify whether user is authenticated. 
Setting cookies immediatly for all apps is a bad idea - what if there are not 2 domains, but 6 domains? :)